# How to trigger an action after a certain amount of time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i want to display an error message if the network connection is too slow after few seconds. How should i implement this?
Here's the code:

```
-(void)setProjectID:(NSString *)newProject {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"projectID"];
    [projectID release];
    projectID = [newProject copy];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"projectID"];

    // Since we have an ID, now we need to load it
    NSInvocation *returnInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                      [Detail instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(configureView:)]];
    [returnInvocation setTarget:self];
    [returnInvocation setSelector:@selector(configureView:)];
    [returnInvocation retainArguments];

    fetch = [[WBWDocumentFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetch retrieveDocument:[NSURL wb_URLForTabType:PROJECT_DETAILS inProject:projectID] returnBy:returnInvocation];
}
-(void)configureView:(NSDictionary *)serverResult 
{
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `performSelector:afterDelay:` or possibly `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

Then, at the beginning of the method called, check to see if the page has loaded. If not, then display a `UIAlertView` and cancel the load.

Comment: on which object should i use this code. I don't see any in my code.

Comment: Also how should i check whether the page has loaded or not?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, it's rather difficult to say. If you are using a `UIWebView`, for example, then you probably want to put it in `-webViewDidStartLoad:`

Comment: Again, without your code, I cannot help. Assuming a `UIWebView`, you can set a `BOOL` in `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` and just read that value in the method above.

Comment: No its not UIWebView. I am just hitting a webservice and getting the response back in xml. SO sometimes its taking a lot of time to load so i want to display some message.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Last time... without code, I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `NSURLRequest` for requesting server than use following code to judge time out.

```
//In this you can set timeoutinterval for request
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]; 

//If request is failing for time out reason you can check that and alert user accordingly.
-(void)connectionFailed:(NSError *)error
{
UIAlertView *objAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init]; 
[objAlert setTitle:@"Internet Connection"];
[objAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
if([error code] == -1001 || [[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"timed out"]){
        [objAlert setMessage:@"Request Timed Out."];
        [objAlert show];
    }
}
```